# Writing a bamboo deployment task

Tags: task, bamboo

I have written a couple of tasks for bamboo. But non of them are available for deployment stage.

I have tried setting the category name to deployment, but still no success.

Here is my task section in atlassian-plugin.xml.

```
<taskType key="MyDeploymentService" name="My Deployment Service" class="za.co.my.bamboo.plugin.MyDeploymentServiceTask">
<category name="deployment"/>
<configuration class="za.co.my.bamboo.plugin.MyDeploymentServiceTaskConfigurator"/>
<resource type="freemarker" name="edit" location="my/editMyDeploymentService.ftl"/>
<resource type="freemarker" name="view" location="my/viewMyDeploymentService.ftl"/>
</taskType>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [TaskType Module Definition](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO030/Tasks+Overview)'s `category` element within `atlassian-plugin.xml` is purely informational, i.e. only determines into which section of [Bamboo](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo)'s [task selection dialog](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOODEV/Tasks+Overview#TasksOverview-SelectingtheTaskType) the task will be sorted.

Section [Introduction to 5.0 - Deployments](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOODEV/Introduction+to+5.0+-+Deployments) within the [Bamboo Developer Documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOODEV/Bamboo+Developer+Documentation) explains the underlying concepts and necessary changes so that a task supports deployment projects:

> Tasks are still a big component of deployments defining each
>   individual step to get a version deployed. [...] You can find a full tutorial on developing Tasks for
>   Bamboo on the [Bamboo Tasks API](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOODEV/Bamboo+Tasks+API) page.  **All existing tasks should work
>   with Bamboo 5.0 builds, but need adjusting to support deployments.** 
>    *[emphasis mine]*

The *differences between Deployment tasks and Build tasks and the changes you might need to make* are highlighted in the subsequent section *Interfaces*:

> To maintain backwards compatibility with existing tasks, the original
>   task interfaces have been left alone.  We have introduced two new
>   interfaces, a super-interface to be used when supporting BOTH builds
>   and deployments and a Deployment specific interface

Check the table there for details. From personal experience I can attest that, assuming your task doesn't use any of the few concepts not supported by deployment tasks (e.g. *Build Definition, Tests, Revisions/Checkouts/Build Changes*), the changes are usually almost trivial to implement as such, i.e. replacing the pre 5.0 now build only interface with the post 5.0 interface that *Supports both Build And Deployment*.